# NLTK: set proxy server

Tags: python, nltk, proxy-server

I'm trying to learn [NLTK](http://nltk.org/index.html) - Natural Language Toolkit written in Python and I want install a sample data set to run some examples.

My web connection uses a proxy server,  and I'm trying to specify the proxy address as follows:

```
>>> nltk.set_proxy('http://proxy.example.com:3128' ('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD'))
>>> nltk.download()
```

But I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I decided to set up a `ProxyBasicAuthHandler` before calling `nltk.download()`:

```
import urllib2

auth_handler = urllib2.ProxyBasicAuthHandler(urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm())
auth_handler.add_password(realm=None, uri='http://proxy.example.com:3128/', user='USERNAME', passwd='PASSWORD')
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

import nltk
nltk.download()
```

But now I get `HTTP Error 407 - Proxy Autentification Required`.

The documentation [says](http://nltk.org/data.html) that if the proxy is set to `None` then this function will attempt to detect the system proxy. But it isn't working.

How can I install a sample data set for NLTK?

Comment: ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348621/ssl-error-downloading-nltk-data set ssl to false if it give error

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is an error with the website where you got those lines of code for your first attempt (I have seen that same error)

The line in error is

```
nltk.set_proxy('http://proxy.example.com:3128' ('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD'))
```

You need a comma to separate the arguments.  The correct line should be

```
nltk.set_proxy('http://proxy.example.com:3128', ('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD'))
```

This will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Documentation of the NLTK project contains errors.

Comment: You can try    
`nltk.set_proxy('http://proxy.example.com:3128', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')`    
If your password contains special characters remember to convert them to hex values.
For example %40 for @

Comment: @demongolem +1 saved me much time, thank you. seemingly nltk does not utilize os.environ['http_proxy'] or os.environ['https_proxy'] proxies as this method did not work for me.

Comment: Work fine. Tested in Python 3.5. 

    nltk.set_proxy('http://proxy.example.com:3128', ('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD'))

Comment: @demongolem Can you help me? For me it works if I use 'http://domen%5Clogin:password@proxy.com:3131' but fails if I try 'http://proxy.com:3131', ('domen%5Clogin' , 'password') . What can be wrong?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam I took a look but I can't say for your particular case.  [The function](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/util.py) if you want to take a look for the two paths: encoding the username and password in the proxy and having the username and password as separate parameters.  Perhaps the `domen\\` portion is it?

Answer (score 13):

I run NLTK 3.2.5 and python 3.6 under Windows 10 environment.
I use this script :

```
nltk.set_proxy('http://user:password@proxy.example.com:3128')
nltk.download()
```

Answer (score 11):

I was too getting the same error but i got a perfectly working solution.**You need to download the nltk_data MANUALLY and put it in usr/lib/nltk_data directory in linux and  c:\nltk_data if you use  windows** .
 Here are the steps you need to follow :
1.Download the nltk_data zip file from this Github link 
 https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/tree/gh-pages .
2.Since data is in zip form you need to extract it .
3.**Specially for ubuntu users** , following command to navigate the filesystem in a handy way.
 **sudo nautilus** it makes copy/paste process handy . Now you can copy to usr/share easily or create a folder easily .
4.Now if you are a linux user than create a folder named as nltk_data in usr/share and if you use windows than create the same in c:/ . 
5.Now paste all content of nltk_data-gh-pages (which you just extracted ) in nltk_data folder you just created . 
6. Now form nltk_data/packages folder copy all folder and paste it to nltk_data folder.
Now you are done. 
*Since this is my first answer i might be not able to explain the process correctly . So if you have trouble going through these steps , please do comment* .

Comment: I am getting the error at https://stackoverflow.com/q/48060011/1352127. Please help

Comment: Just an extra comment to make the answer more productive.. Make a recursive extraction of the zips (because inside the packages, there will be more zips, that should be unzipped too).

Comment: Directory doesn't have to be necessarily c:/drive (for win). it can be any path inside >>> nltk.data.path

Answer (score 6):

The options suggested above did not work for me. Here's what worked for me in my windows environment. Try removing the round braces . it works now !

```
nltk.set_proxy('http://proxy.example.com:3128', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')
```

Answer (score 2):

I run NLTK 3.0 and python 3.4 in windows environment..and proxy authentication runs well if i remove the branch..
so use this script

```
nltk.set_proxy('http://proxy.example.com:3128', 'username', 'password')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to manually install NLTK Corpus.

1) Go to http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/ and download your desired NLTK Corpus file.

2) Now in a Python shell check the value of `nltk.data.path`

3) Choose one of the path that exists on your machine, and unzip the data files into the `corpora` sub directory inside.

4) Now you can import the data `from nltk.corpos import stopwords`

Reference: https://medium.com/@satorulogic/how-to-manually-download-a-nltk-corpus-f01569861da9

Answer (score 1):

Set the proxy of the system in bash also by changing proper environment variable.

Some of the proxy settings which I keep are:

```
http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3129/
ftp_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3129/
all_proxy=socks://127.0.0.1:3129/
https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3129/
```

You can make the changes in environment variable permanent by editing your ~/.bashrc file. Sample edit:

```
export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3129/
```

Comment: I'm already use `http_proxy` environment variable and many programs (such as eclipse, git, wget, etc.) use it. But it seems to me that NLTK downloader don't use environment variable.

Comment: In my system, it works perfectly. I also use a proxy.
`>>> import nltk >>> nltk.download()
NLTK Downloader
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    d) Download      l) List      c) Config      h) Help      q) Quit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloader> `

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, the accepted solution doesn't work for me. And I'm also afraid of leaking my password since we need to specify it explicitly.

Rather than use `nltk.download()` inside python console, run `python -m nltk.downloader all` in cmd (for Windows) works super for me!

ps:
For Windows user, remember to turn of your Proxy server before running the command. 
Go to **Internet Explorer** -> **gear icon** at the top right -> **Internet Options** -> **Connections** -> **LAN settings** -> ***uncheck*** "User a proxy server ... VPN connections)." -> **OK**

Resource is also from the official document: https://www.nltk.org/data.html#command-line-installation

Answer (score -2):

I could make it work with:

```
nltk.set_proxy('http://user_name:password@proxy_ip_adress:3128')
```