# "pattern" package for python 3.6 Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I have Anaconda environment on my machine for python 3.6
When I try to install **pattern** package through pip, it gave an error saying something like

> parentheses around print n

Then I tried `conda install -c asmeurer pattern=2.5;` as well as `conda install -c asmeurer pattern`.
It says

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict: - pattern -> python 2.7* -
>    python 3.6*"

Finally, I got to know that python 3 does not have pattern directly.

So, I tried downloading pattern zip from http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pattern.
Now, when I ran `python ./setup.py install`. It again give errors related to **parentheses around print n**

I have tried almost everything, but unable to install pattern package in my python 3.6 Anaconda environment.
Can someone please help me out here , some workaround for this?

Comment: If you want to use pip: in Anaconda Command Prompt, cd to C:\Anaconda\Scripts, and use pip from there.

Answer (score 10):

I installed PIP with Conda

```
conda install pip
```

and then installed Pattern with

```
pip install Pattern3
```

it worked :)

Comment: Are you using python 3.6 ?

Comment: Collecting Pattern
  Using cached pattern-2.6.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\jatin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-r_d_2wek\Pattern\setup.py", line 40
        print n
              ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\jatin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-r_d_2wek\Pattern\

Comment: I tried that too. But getting the same error as mentioned in above comment. Also, it says "using cached pattern-2.6.zip". can that be an issue ?

Comment: the error because of Pattern 2.6 not compatible with Python 3

Comment: So, what is the solution for this? I am not even mentioning the package version.

Comment: There are really only two fixes to this problem: Use version 2.x instead, or find a library built for version 3.x.

Comment: Sorry, but you mentioned that you were able to install it for python 3.6. The library you got must be compatible with 3.x right ?

Comment: Yes i am sorry i forgot mention that i use pattern3 instead of pattern

Comment: pip install Pattern3 worked. Thanks a lot for ur help Masume. You saved me a ton of time. Really appreciate it. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how this relates to Anaconda, but this worked for me to get **pattern.en working in python 3.6**:

```
git clone -b development https://github.com/clips/pattern
cd pattern
sudo python3.6 setup.py install
```

https://github.com/clips/pattern/issues/62

I had some SSL errors during installation on my mac (10.11.6) that were fixed by running this code in python (3.6):

```
import nltk
import ssl 

try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context

nltk.download('wordnet_ic')
```

apparently there's a better way to deal with ssl stuff like this fwiw:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41351871/8870055

sanity check:

```
user@USDR00253 ~> python3.6
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48ecebad5, Dec 18 2017, 21:07:28)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> from pattern.en import conjugate, lemma, lexeme, parse
>>>
>>> print(parse('ridden', relations=True, lemmata=True))
ridden/VBN/B-VP/O/O/ride
>>>
```

pattern.en finally running in python3!

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows Subsystem for Linux, I made pattern to work using miniconda in Python 3.7:

```sh
conda create -n test -c conda-forge python=3.7 pattern
conda activate test
```

I discovered that there is a bug with StopInteration due to PEP-479, and [replacing](https://github.com/clips/pattern/pull/251/files) `raise StopIteration` with `return` in `pattern\text\__init__.py` fixes it.

To find the location if the file, I executed

```
cd $(python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib;print(get_python_lib())")
nano pattern/text/__init__.py
```

[Line 605](https://github.com/clips/pattern/pull/251/files), just above `class Lexicon(lazydict): ...` replace `raise StopIteration` with `return`.

And all is working fine.

[image]