# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 when installing 'pattern

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, pip

Am trying to install pattern on python 3.6 with the command prompt using:

```
pip3 install pattern
```

But am getting this error :

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip3 install pattern
Collecting pattern
  Using cached pattern-2.6.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-u_5lhmfa\pattern\setup.py", line 40
        print n
              ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(int n)?

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-u_5lhmfa\pattern\
```

By the way I have Python 2.7 installed as well and when I installed with `pip2 install pattern`, it perfectly installed.

The problem is with python 3.6. How can I fix this?

Comment: Download and install it directly from Pypi seems to be your best option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pattern-2.6 at PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pattern/2.6) seems to be rather old (last updated in 2014). They [require](https://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/pattern) Python 2.5+. I think the code is Python2-only, you cannot use it with Python 3.

[Pattern3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pattern3) seems to be the package for Python 3:

```
pip install pattern3
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how but this really worked for me:

Running command prompt as an administrator then :

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/clips/pattern@development
```

This install pattern as more packages.

Am posting this in case it would help anyone

More details :[["pattern" package for python 3.6 Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44234796/pattern-package-for-python-3-6-anaconda]) ]

Comment: Development branch: 411 commits ahead of master. It seems they've updated the code for Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Python3 support is as discussed in this issue: https://github.com/clips/pattern

From [pip install from git repo branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch)

```
pip install -U https://github.com/clips/pattern/archive/development.zip
```