# python -m textblob.download_corpora - CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python, textblob

I am trying to run some python code, using textblob.
This is the following code:

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
from textblob import TextBlob
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

analysis = TextBlob("TextBlob sure looks like it has some interesting         
features")

print(analysis.tags)
```

On running it, it told me i was missing this so I ran it...

```
Looks like you are missing some required data for this feature.

To download the necessary data, simply run

python -m textblob.download_corpora

or use the NLTK downloader to download the missing data:         
http://nltk.org/data.html
If this doesn't fix the problem, file an issue at 
https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/issues.
```

So when I ran that it gave me this failed attempt. I can't figure out how to correct the error.

```
$ python -m textblob.download_corpora
[nltk_data] Error loading brown: <urlopen error [SSL:
[nltk_data]     CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
[nltk_data]     (_ssl.c:833)>
[nltk_data] Error loading punkt: <urlopen error [SSL:
[nltk_data]     CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
[nltk_data]     (_ssl.c:833)>
[nltk_data] Error loading wordnet: <urlopen error [SSL:
[nltk_data]     CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
[nltk_data]     (_ssl.c:833)>
[nltk_data] Error loading averaged_perceptron_tagger: <urlopen error
[nltk_data]     [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
[nltk_data]     failed (_ssl.c:833)>
[nltk_data] Error loading conll2000: <urlopen error [SSL:
[nltk_data]     CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
[nltk_data]     (_ssl.c:833)>
[nltk_data] Error loading movie_reviews: <urlopen error [SSL:
[nltk_data]     CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
[nltk_data]     (_ssl.c:833)>
Finished.
```

Any ideas on the cause?

Answer (score 4):

The answer was found here: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348621/ssl-error-downloading-nltk-data/42890688#42890688)

Go to applications/python 3.6/ and double click on the install certificates file.

Then you can run...

```
python -m textblob.download_corpora
```

And it works!