# Overcome SSL error while downloading NLTK data, but inside a virtual environment on macOS with Homebrew-installed Python

Tags: python, macos, ssl, nltk

I've pip-installed NLTK, and am trying to download corpora with `nltk.download()`. The GUI pops up, but then I get this error, as shown below:

`[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)`

[image]

There are several questions and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42890688/2786201) about this generally, but none of them appear to help if you're running a Python other than the one shipped on python.org. In my case, I'm running a Python 3.6 that I installed through [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), and that inside a virtual environment (using pipenv, if that's relevant). As a result, I do not have any version of Python that comes with the `Install Certificates.command` script mentioned in other answers.

This code will eventually run in production, so disabling SSL certificate checking is unacceptable.

Now to the question: Given this setup, what is the *right way*, reproducibly (i.e., on fresh machines) and without ugly hacks, to overcome this SSL error and download NLTK corpora?

Comment: You *may* need to have your sysadmin administer you a valid cert that you can put into the `REQUESTS_CA_CERT` environment var. In Mac, this should be part of your `bash_profile`

Comment: Thanks, @C.Nivs I tried this out but it didn't work. Details: https://gist.github.com/anseljh/74b442de518f189dbe4a5fa39940fed2

Comment: What is your output of `import sys;  print(sys.version_info)`?

Comment: @alvas: `sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`

Comment: What is the output of `which python` on the terminal?

Comment: @alvas: `(repo-name-s7XLw6jn) repo-name $ which python` gives `/Users/anseljh/.local/share/virtualenvs/repo-name-s7XLw6jn/bin/python` and `(repo-name-s7XLw6jn) repo-name $ python --version` gives `Python 3.6.5`

Comment: What is the output of `ls /Users/anseljh/.local/share/virtualenvs/repo-name-s7XLw6jn/bin/` on ther terminal?