# Error related to nltk.download('stopwords')

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

When I run the following Python code in my local Jupyter notebook (in macOS)

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk.download('stopwords')
```

I got the following errors:

```
[nltk_data] Error loading stopwords: <urlopen error [SSL:
[nltk_data]     CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed:
[nltk_data]     unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)>
```

Comment: Does this work ? `python -c "import nltk;nltk.download('stopwords')"`

Comment: I typed in the above code from the terminal, and it gave me the following error:
`zsh: command not found: python`.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by typing in `sh "/Applications/Python 3.11/Install Certificates.command"` in my terminal. I got hint from this link ([SSL error downloading NLTK data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348621/ssl-error-downloading-nltk-data?rq=2)).